# Why isn't electric potential infinite?

Tags: work, potential, potential-energy, voltage, coulombs-law

In my textbook, I've read that electric potential is the work performed to carry one unit of positive charge to electric field from infinite distance.

We know that, W = Fs

So here the distance is infinity and W = F × infinity = infinity

But I have never seen potential's being infinity. So what is the problem here actually?

Comment: What happens if $F\propto1/s^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$W=Fs$ only when the force is constant.  In general,
$$
W=-\int_a^b \vec F\cdot d\vec r
$$
for a path from $a$ to $b$.  In the case of the electric potential,
$$
W=-q \int_{\infty}^b \vec E\cdot d\vec r = -q\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}
 \int_{\infty}^b \frac{1}{r^2}\cdot d\vec r=\frac{qQ}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{b}
$$